# what is the best practice to collect user behavior data in web app?

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, single-page-application, vuejs2

I'm not a professional web developer. just learnt some front-end framework like angular 4 and vue 2.0 and sort of other stuff which enabled me to build some web applications(SPA) and use AWS lambda as the "serverless" backend.

Anyone know what is the best practice to collect user behavior data from a SPA? I don't think http request is a good way here. Socket.io?, AWS IoT? any recommendations?

Comment: Choose one from the tools in the link: https://www.inc.com/guides/12/2010/11-best-web-analytics-tools.html

Comment: Google analytics and possibly Clicky analytics (https://clicky.com/) which gives heatmaps of user webpage interactions. (I haven't used clicky or looked over them too much, but I ran across them a few days ago, and they seem like a decent option for this.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally to implement user behavior analytic service, request response architecture is not the right choice due to its scalability limitations.

For this, its recommended to use complex event processing(stream processing) using middleware(e.g [AWS Kinesis](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/streams/), [WSO2 Complex Event Processor](http://wso2.com/products/complex-event-processor/)  & etc) where the messages are buffered and processed as batches, inside a moving time window, to get near realtime analytics.

Having said that, there are plenty of SaaS solutions out there like Google Analytics which does all the heavy lifting where you can focus on configuration and integration to get the behavior result you need.